# How to detect a Kill Process event

Tags: c#, process, kill

In C# i using process.Kill() kill a process,
at the same time in killed application how to detect this event?

BTW: Application.ApplicationExit event has not been fired!

Comment: Perhaps this isn't in the spirit of your question, but it's important to note that there will always be a mechanism available to the user to forcibly kill your process without letting your process "handle" or "detect" the event.  What are you trying to do in your "detection" code?

Comment: @Reuben 
if window closing or application exit i will save some data,and this is necessary for my application.

Comment: My point is this... you can't *depend* on getting a chance to save data, particularly in case of unexpected termination of your process.  You can certainly try to do this as much as possible, but you have to be aware that there will always be some event that could cause your application to exit without giving you a chance to save data.  (For instance, the system's power cord could be unplugged.)  I don't mean to be picky, I just wanted to point this out for others  with a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a winform, you can capture the event `FormClosing` and check the `CloseReason`:

```
None
WindowsShutDown
MdiFormClosing
UserClosing
TaskManagerClosing
FormOwnerClosing
ApplicationExitCall
```

Comment: But if using process.Kill() method ,FormClosing event has not been fired

Comment: @guaike, thats the way OS is, it cant give you a reason when it is forcibly killed.

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple ways of accomplishing this, though code injecting, api hooking, and a number of other techniques could be used to accomplish this very goal, but my question to you is, do you really want to go through a lot of extra work just to make sure your application is aware of an unexpected termination? You would have to ensure that you code injected/hooked (or whatever method your chose) every single possible method someone else could use to terminate your application, when someone does make one of those calls your application can trigger its own event indicating that it should process such an event and prepare to exit. Essentially you could also use this to stop anyone else from being able to close your application as well.

If you want more information about any of these techniques let me know and I'll post some links. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I'm interested in this topic. Could You provide some links where I can read more about this? Thanks in advance.