# ASP.Net Application Data not updating when application forcibly end

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I have asp.net application.

I am forcibly ending this application and on the time of that i want to update my view page count value in `database`.

I am forcibly stopping my application that time `Application_End()` not firing in `Global.aspx` file. when i stop process normally then `Application_End() event` fired. but my requirement is that,

Data should be update in both cases forcibly or gracefully stop application. Suggest me for better solution or what other event should i use.

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code that runs on application shut`enter code here`down
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I where you i would take a look at this question: 
[How to detect a Kill Process event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372250/how-to-detect-a-kill-process-event)

One of the comment says

> My point is this... you can't depend on getting a chance to save data, particularly in case of unexpected termination of your process. You can certainly try to do this as much as possible, but you have to be aware that there will always be some event that could cause your application to exit without giving you a chance to save data. (For instance, the system's power cord could be unplugged.) I don't mean to be picky, I just wanted to point this out for others with a similar question.  -reuben

If the kind of data you are working with really are crutial, i would recommend saving them at the moment you are able to do it. waiting for the application to be shutted down before saving data is asking for trouble.

Comment: how to use this link for web application. because this solution for window application

Comment: The point of my answer is that you will never ever be able to catch all of the possible ways that your application might shut down. The best way would be to save your data on a regular basis.